# "Prompting policy for hardened runtime; invalid entitlement" error for sending Apple Event

Tags: xcode, electron, code-signing

I'm trying to send an Apple Event to another process, and am getting an error indicating I don't have the proper entitlements:

```
Prompting policy for hardened runtime; invalid entitlement for responsible={identifier=com.ishaangandhi.ishan, pid=1595, auid=501, euid=501, responsible_path=/path/to/my/Shell Notebook, binary_path=/path/to/my/Shell Notebook.app/Contents/MacOS/Shell Notebook}, accessing={identifier=com.barebones.bbedit-tool, pid=1613, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/Helpers/bbedit_tool}, requesting={identifier=com.apple.appleeventsd, pid=303, auid=55, euid=55, binary_path=/System/Library/CoreServices/appleeventsd},
```

I have the following values in my Info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow Shell Notebook to run Apple scripts.</string>  
    <key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
    <string>YES</string>
</dict>
```

And this key in my entitlements.plist:

```
    <key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
    <string>YES</string>
```

What else do I need to be allowed to send Apple Events? When I try to send them, the user never gets prompted to allow them, unlike with other apps.

This is an electron app, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue after a few hours:

```
    <key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
    <string>YES</string>
```

will fail.

```
    <key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
    <true/>
```

works.

Comment: I added plist and entitlements same but it does not work on m1 chip. Works on intel chips though.